# Get values from array php in inputs and repeat inputs in a block

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I have several inputs where I obtain the values from arrays in database.
I need all the inputs repeated as a block and not to repeat the html I am trying to write the html only once, but then don't know how to get the values using foreach.

So I have inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" name="x[]" value="<?php echo $p;?>">
<input type="text" name2="y[]" value="<?php echo $refarray;?>">
etc.
```

I need to fill in the values like this:

```
foreach ($x as $p){
foreach ($y as $r){ ?>
```

I want to repeat the block 3 times so I run it 3 times in a while loop:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$times_to_run = 3;
while ($i++ < $times_to_run)
{ 
?>
    <input type="text" name="x[]" value="<?php echo $p;?>">
    <input type="text" name2="y[]" value="<?php echo $r;?>">
<?php
}
?>
```

This is how I want the output to be printed out:

```
Block 1
<input type="text" name="x[]" value="<?php echo $p[0];?>">
<input type="text" name2="y[]" value="<?php echo $r[0];?>">
Block 2
<input type="text" name="x[]" value="<?php echo $p[1];?>">
<input type="text" name2="y[]" value="<?php echo $r[1];?>">
Block 3
<input type="text" name="x[]" value="<?php echo $p[2];?>">
<input type="text" name2="y[]" value="<?php echo $r[2];?>">
```

How can I do this without writing the html 3 times?

Comment: Why write html three times? You already have a loop which runs 3 times

Comment: You need to make `name="x"` to `name="x[]"` otherwise when form will submit, you will get only last value.

Comment: Yes I know, forgot that thanks.

Comment: I don't want to repeat, however don't know how to print out the values in the inputs if already in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have array in `$x` and `$r` with key 0,1,2,3....etc.

using foreach will be easy and clean to bind with html

```
foreach ($x as $key => $p){ 
   echo  '<input type="text" name="x[]" value="<?php echo $p;?>">';
   echo  '<input type="text" name="y[]" value="<?php echo $r[$key];?>">';

}
```

Comment: This works perfect, no need to use the loop for running it 3 times

Comment: final code: foreach ($titleenvarios as $key => $titleenvarios2){
                ?>
                  <input type="text" name="ref" value="<?php echo $propertyref[$key];?>">
                  <input type="text" name="titleen[]" value="<?php echo $titleenvarios[$key];?>">
                  <input type="text"name="titlees[]" value="<?php echo $titleesvarios[$key];?>">
<?php
}
?>
Thanks